# How to play sound on our local server through ssh without logging in on that server?

Tags: command-line, ssh, sox

I'm using sox to play a sound on our local server (ubuntu 16.04). I run play myfile.mp3 through ssh.

However, that sound only plays if I'm logged in on that local server. Any idea how to achieve this even if nobody is logged in?

Thx

[EDIT] the goal is not to log in, do something then log out and keep it running. The goal is to play that sound on the local server over ssh without having to log in on the local server's GUI at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start the player directly with a oneliner, do e.g.:

```bsh
ssh user@host 'cvlc music/Ratatat/LP4'   # VLC opens whole directories
ssh user@host 'play music/Ratatat/LP4/*' # SoX don't
```

---

If you're in a `ssh` session and want a process to remain running after you `exit`ed, you can use `disown` to disconnect the process from the shell that runs it:

```
$ ssh user@host
$ cvlc music/Nick_McKaig & disown
$ exit
```

That's the easy way, however you're not able to return to the session as it's possible with `screen` (see [Max' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/978863/507051)) or `tmux`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try at the office tomorrow and mark as valid response. I'm quite surprised that vlc could play without login and not sox!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the program screen on the server (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen, http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install screen # if not installed on the server
```

Login via SSH and start a screen

```bsh
$ screen -S my_sound_bash
```

start you music. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to leave the current screen session and you can logout. The music should still play.

You can login again using SSH and with

```bsh
$ screen -r my_sound_bash
```

you should get your running player back.

Answer (score 1):

Try your command with **sudo**

*`sudo mpv myfile.mp3`* and it's actually starts playing on speaker

It's very likely a problem with *permissions*
e.g. if you are running Pulseaudio. With the right permissions, you can play sounds on the remote machine via ssh just fine.

We need to update the permissions of pulseaudio ( atleast in my case ) because it's work fine with sudo

Hope it's helps.